# Computer won't boot into Windows when discrete GPU is removed

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, reboot, amd-radeon, intel-core-i5

I'm trying to return my Radeon HD 6870 which is breaking (The fan doesn't work, and it overheats). However when I remove it from the PC, and revert to using the HD3000 in my i5 2500k, it refuses to start Windows.

I run a Hackintosh, and when I select Windows, my PC just restarts. If I connect the GPU back up, without using it to drive any displays, Windows will start.

I have tried reinstalling then uninstalling the Catalyst drivers, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: What's the last thing that happens before it restarts?

Comment: Have you checked the BIOS to make sure it is set to use the integrated video as the primary display?  Are you able to boot into safe mode?  Have you removed the card from the list of devices in device manager and uninstalled any associated programs from Windows?

Comment: This is a driver problem.  You need to remove the current drivers for your Radeon HD 6870 card.  You need to tell Windows to remove the device, after you remove the Catalyst driver.